# Python: "Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data)."

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, time-series, arima

I'm trying to create an ARIMA model for forecasting a time-serie with some data from my server, and i keep the error on the title showing up and i don't know what type of object i need. Here's the code:

```
frame = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
connection.close()
frame['time_field'] = pd.to_timedelta(frame['time_field'])
print(frame.head(10))
#fitting
model = ARIMA(frame, order=(5,1,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
```

i've seen examples like this one:
 https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/

where they use dates instead of times with the respectives values. This is the output of the frame value:

```
time_field   value_field
0 00:00:14  283.80
1 00:01:14  271.97
2 00:02:14  320.53
3 00:03:14  346.78
4 00:04:14  280.72
5 00:05:14  277.41
6 00:06:14  308.65
7 00:07:14  321.27
8 00:08:14  320.68
9 00:09:14  332.32
```

Comment: Why are you connection to mysql? Pandas abstracts this away.

Comment: I'm connecting to mysql because that's the only server i have available right now, and i'm formatting it's output as a frame becasue that's the input format for the ARIMA function

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make the "time_field" column as the index of your data frame(in the ARIMA model, we should always set the date time column as the index of the data frame)

```
frame=frame.set_index('time_field')
model = ARIMA(frame, order=(5,1,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
```

Note:- When you're setting up the index column, you may get error if the index column has any duplicate values. So in that case, you better do a group by summation.

```
frame = frame.groupby(['time_field']).agg({'value_field': 'sum'}) 
or
frame = frame.groupby(['time_field']).sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and worked for me using pandas `Series` instead of the `DataFrame`, with the timestamp column as index

```
data = pd.Series(frame.value_fields, index=frame.time_field)
model = ARIMA(data, order=(5,1,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
```

Comment: data = pd.Series(frame.value_fields.values, index=frame.time_field) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

after time column is set as index you no longer need to pass it to ARIMA, just drop it.

frame = frame[['value_field']]